# Fitting a curve for given data and minimizing the norm

Tags: normed-spaces, matlab

I have some data points give by function $f_1(x)$. I don't know what is the formual of $f_1(x)$. I just have the domain and range. I have to approximate the function using say exponential function, $f_2(x)$ given by $\alpha e^{-\beta x}$

I have to estimate the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that

$||f_1(x)-f_2(x)||_{norm}$ is minimized. where norm can be 1, 2 or infinity

I am not sure if I have to post it to stackoverflow or here but i assumed it would be more appropriate here. I assume this is to be done in MATLAB. But i am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right place for this question. None-the-less, the *fit(X, Y, 'exp1')*  [function](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/curvefitting/mw/curvefit-ex72685292-fit-exponential-models-using-the-fit-function) will fit the least squares (aka the 2-norm. Not sure about the 1 and $\infty$ norms).